# Error and warning connecting MongoDB to PHP using php_mongodb extension

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp, php-5.6

I installed the MongoDB PHP driver on Windows 10 (I'm using WAMP equipped with PHP 5.6.25.  following the istructions I found at http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php and I installed also the **libbson** and **libmongoc** libraries (requested as requirements) as written at http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.requirements.php.
Then, I added the bin folders of MongoDB, libbson and libmongoc to system path.
 
However, even if I can see the php_mongodb extension in the extensions list of WAMP, launching phpinfo() the mongo extension doesn't appear with the others.
Furthermore, tryng to connect to my database with

```
<?php
 $mongo=new MongoClient("");
 $db=$mongo->galileo;
 $collection= $db->items;
print_r("Number of documens: "); ?>
```

I got the error

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in C:\wamp64\www\galileo\index.php >on line 21

At a first look, reading this error, it might seem like that PHP is looking for php_mongodb extension in the uncorrect folder i.e. **C:\wamp64\www\galileo\index.php** (where the index page of my project is placed) instead of the correct one **C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext** where all the extensions are. 
But, looking at php log file **php_error.log** I find also a warning that says:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_mongodb.dll' - Il sistema operativo non pu� eseguire %1.
>   in Unknown on line 0.

(for not Italian speaking, the phrase after - means *the operating system can't execute %1*, even if I can't imagine what *%1* stands for).
Even using the new class **MongoDB\Driver\Manager** I get the error

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in C:\wamp64\www\galileo\index.php on line 21

and the same warning.
Do you notice some error or forgetfulness in the installation process as I described and, if not, do you know how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is certainly related to WAMP and I think is related to the multiple php.ini in his folders. In fact, in the **apache** folder you can find a php.ini file that cannot be modified, otherwise nothing works at all; at the same time any changes made to the php.ini file in the **php** folder seems have no effect except making appear the mongodb extension in the extensions list.
So, I try using XAMPP, as suggested in this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gEPiIoAHo8) and it works. Using Composer I was able to install also the PHP library and not only the driver.

Comment: I followed the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gEPiIoAHo8) for WAMP and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use 'MongoClient class' anymore, this extension that defines this class is deprecated. look at [here](http://php.net/MongoClient).

instead, you should use MongoDB\Driver\Manager class. please read http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php.

and the setup must be like this in php:

```
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

And if you still use the old class; you either need to install the old legacy extension (pecl install mongo) and use PHP 5.x, or update your code to use this new driver's classes as the old driver is not available for PHP 7. There is an upgrade guide at [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/upgrade-guide/).

the last part is from derickr's answer in this issue on github: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/300

Comment: I tried also MongoDB\Driver\Manager as you suggested but the issue is still there, even this class is not found.